# Mule SOAP Proxy WSDL fails at relative path resolution of XSD

Tags: soap, xsd, wsdl, mule, mule-studio

I have created a WSDL and a Mule SOAP proxy web service using the MuleSoft [XML Only SOAP Web Service example](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XML-only+SOAP+Web+Service+Example).  My application is working fine except for one issue:  When the XSD is stored anywhere other than the root of the project, it will not resolve.  I created folders of service and xsd inside /src/main/resources as shown in the example project, however when the service is invoked I receive the following error:

[[bpi.sfdcservices].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.apache.cxf.wstx_msv_validation.ResolvingGrammarReaderController: C:\Users\mmrg\MuleStudio\workspace\bpi.sfdcservices\xsd\sfdcServicesApiTypes.xsd (The system cannot find the path specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\mmrg\MuleStudio\workspace\bpisfdcservices\xsd\sfdcServicesApiTypes.xsd (The system cannot find the path specified)

The xsd is imported as:

```
<xs:import namespace="BPI/Types" schemaLocation="xsd/sfdcServicesApiTypes.xsd"/>
```

If I change this location to

```
<xs:import namespace="BPI/Types" schemaLocation="sfdcServicesApiTypes.xsd"/>
```

And place the xsd in the root of the project, the service executes normally.

The WSDL is able to be referenced in the class path/relative pathing.

```
<cxf:proxy-service namespace="BPI/sfdcServices/1.0" service="sfdcServices"  payload="body" doc:name="SOAP" port="sfdcServicesHttpSoapEndpoint" wsdlLocation="service/sfdcServices.wsdl" validationEnabled="true"/>
```

From what I can see my project is set up the same as the Mule example.  I do not see any specific mappings etc in their configuration.  I'm suspecting there is something off about the way my WSDL/XSD is written since it behaves the same when I imported all of my project files into the example project, but cannot figure out the issue.

sfdcServices.wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="SFDCServices" targetNamespace="BPI/sfdcServices/1.0" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="BPI/sfdcServices/1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:btns="BPI/Types" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" >
    <wsdl:documentation>Services for CRU operations in SFDC</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="BPI/sfdcServices/1.0" xmlns:soap11-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:import namespace="BPI/Types" schemaLocation="xsd/sfdcServicesApiTypes.xsd"/>
            <xs:element name="querySFDCSingleRequest" type="btns:querySFDCSingleRequest"/>
            <xs:element name="querySFDCSingleResponse" type="btns:querySFDCSingleResponse"/>
            <xs:element name="updateSFDCSingleRequest" type="btns:updateSFDCSingleRequest"/>
            <xs:element name="updateSFDCSingleResponse" type="btns:updateSFDCSingleResponse"/>
            <xs:element name="createSFDCSingleRequest" type="btns:createSFDCSingleRequest"/>
            <xs:element name="createSFDCSingleResponse" type="btns:createSFDCSingleResponse"/>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:documentation>Query for a single sObject</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:message name="querySFDCSingleRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part name="querySFDCSingleRequestPart" element="tns:querySFDCSingleRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="querySFDCSingleResponseMsg">
        <wsdl:part name="querySFDCSingleResponsePart" element="tns:querySFDCSingleResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:documentation>Update a single sObject</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:message name="updateSFDCSingleRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part name="updateSFDCSingleRequestPart" element="tns:updateSFDCSingleRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="updateSFDCSingleResponseMsg">
        <wsdl:part name="updateSFDCSingleResponsePart" element="tns:updateSFDCSingleResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:documentation>Create a single sObject</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:message name="createSFDCSingleRequestMsg">
        <wsdl:part name="createSFDCSingleRequestPart" element="tns:createSFDCSingleRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="createSFDCSingleResponseMsg">
        <wsdl:part name="createSFDCSingleResponsePart" element="tns:createSFDCSingleResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="sfdcServicesSOAP">
        <wsdl:operation name="querySFDCSingle">
            <wsdl:input name="querySFDCSingleRequestInput" message="tns:querySFDCSingleRequestMsg"/>
            <wsdl:output name="querySFDCSingleResponseOutput" message="tns:querySFDCSingleResponseMsg"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="updateSFDCSingle">
            <wsdl:input name="updateSFDCSingleRequestInput" message="tns:updateSFDCSingleRequestMsg"/>
            <wsdl:output name="updateSFDCSingleResponseOutput" message="tns:updateSFDCSingleResponseMsg"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="createSFDCSingle">
            <wsdl:input name="createSFDCSingleRequestInput" message="tns:createSFDCSingleRequestMsg"/>
            <wsdl:output name="createSFDCSingleResponseOutput" message="tns:createSFDCSingleResponseMsg"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="sfdcServicesSoapBinding" type="tns:sfdcServicesSOAP">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="querySFDCSingle">
            <soap:operation soapAction="querySFDCSingle" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="querySFDCSingleRequestInput">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="querySFDCSingleResponseOutput">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="updateSFDCSingle">
            <soap:operation soapAction="updateSFDCSingle" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="updateSFDCSingleRequestInput">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="updateSFDCSingleResponseOutput">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="createSFDCSingle">
            <soap:operation soapAction="createSFDCSingle" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="createSFDCSingleRequestInput">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="createSFDCSingleResponseOutput">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="sfdcServices">
        <wsdl:port name="sfdcServicesHttpSoapEndpoint" binding="tns:sfdcServicesSoapBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8084/BPI/services/sfdcServices"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

sfdcServicesApiTypes.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns1="BPI/Types" targetNamespace="BPI/Types" elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="querySFDCSingleRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="sObjectType" type="xs:string" nillable="false"/>
            <xs:element name="queryFilterField" type="xs:string" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="queryCondition" type="ns1:queryCondition" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="querySFDCSingleResponse">
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="updateSFDCSingleRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="sObjectType" type="xs:string" nillable="false"/>
            <xs:element name="Id" type="xs:string" nillable="false"/>
            <xs:element name="fieldUpdates" type="ns1:dataPair" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="updateSFDCSingleResponse">
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="createSFDCSingleRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="sObjectType" type="xs:string" nillable="false"/>
            <xs:element name="fieldUpdates" type="ns1:dataPair" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="createSFDCSingleResponse">
        <xs:sequence/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="dataPair">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="fieldName" type="xs:string" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="queryCondition">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="queryField" type="xs:string" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="operator" type="xs:string" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: add src/main/resources to your class path or add them to the import statement and then try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  src/main/java, src/main/resources, src/test/java, and src/test/resources are all on the build path by default in the Mule project.  I have other files in the resources dir that are referenced from the class path succesfully (properties files, and the sfdcServices.wsdl file itself can be referenced as 'service/sfdcServices.wsdl').  I checked the example project and there was nothing additional included in the build path.

Comment: So the issue seems to actually be the CXF validator.  When validation of the message is turned off, the service runs fine and the XSD is parsed from the class path.  The validator appears to be attempting to validate the XSD using the path given relative to the Working Directory.  This working directory changes when moving between Studio and muleESB standalone.  This gets us up and running but I would still like to be able to manipulate the value sent to CXF so that we could continue to use message validation.

Comment: @MikeM, how can I turned off the validation?